# Drawing Country Borders as Polygons

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I am developing an Android Application using the Google Maps API (v2). I do want to display Country Borders, but not Country Names or any other information (a mute map). *The purpose of application is creating Geography game.*

Taking into account that, as stated in the documentation, [The Google Maps Android API does not support custom styles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lite#supported_api_features), I first thought about drawing each country border as lines (using [Polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes#polylines)). So then, I googled a bit and found an already done [Polygon approximation of all countries](http://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1zn8cjdD6qlAFI7ALMEnwn89g50weLi1D-bAGSZw). It is in KML format, which is easy to import to Google Earth application and also to Google Maps [with some limitations](https://support.google.com/mapsengine/answer/2505884?hl=en), but I have been unable to find importation methods to Android.

A country in a KML file has a format **similar** to the following (downloaded as csv) in case the country just needs a single Polygon to be representated:

```
Andorra,"
<Polygon>
    <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>
                 1.78172,42.569962 1.723611,42.509438 1.445833,42.601944 1.78172,42.569962
             </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
     </outerBoundaryIs>
</Polygon>"
```

And this format if it has more than one Polygon:

```
Mayotte,"
<MultiGeometry>
    <Polygon>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
                <coordinates>
                    45.282494,-12.80417 45.262497,-12.76889 45.283051,-12.7475 45.282494,-12.80417
                </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
    <Polygon>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
                <coordinates>
                    45.204994,-12.84972 45.097496,-12.985834 45.078888,-12.6625 45.204994,-12.84972
                </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
</MultiGeometry>
```

Being in this step, a solution came into my mind:

- Parse this KML file *directly* at the Android Application (at the launch of the Activity), drawing each **Polygon**:

```
// Instantiates a new Polygon object and adds points to define a rectangle
PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions()
    .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0),
    new LatLng(37.45, -122.0),
    new LatLng(37.45, -122.2),
    new LatLng(37.35, -122.2),
    new LatLng(37.35, -122.0));


myMap.addPolygon(rectOptions);
```

---

I could have made the solution work, but as I wanted more features like painting only some Continent, the solution was not enough.

So finally, I thought that it would be better (and more understandable) to transform the KML file to a XML file (and having a strong Python base, thought that XMLs are pretty easy to parse) with the following structure:

```
<continent name="Europe">
    <country name="Andorra">
        //As many polygons as necessary
        <poligon1>
         //Coordinates go here
         </poligon1>

        <poligonN>
        //Coordinates go here
        </poligonN>
    </country>
</continent>
```

I do already know how to transform the KML to the XML, but there are many parsers in Android like DOM, SAX, XMLPull...:

- Which would be the most suitable one for these case? (The KML file size is 850kB).
- Could you provide some examples/hints of how I would have to do to go over all polygons in a continent?

> Please, note that this idea of going through XMLs is **not fixed** and
>   if someone has other ideas, I would be glad to hear them.